# Jenkins how to execute particular shell command from the git commit message

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, spoon, commit-message

I have 3 test commands to run on post build but I want to run these commands based on keyword in the git commit message.

```
Commit message: 'New changes [CoreTest]'

if(CoreTest){
   Run coreTest shell command for spoon
}else if(CloudTest){
   Run CloudTest shell command for spoon
}
else{
   AllTests shell command for spoon
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [parametrized plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) to do this job

( pass Coretest value as parameter )